# running hadoop wordcount example

Tags: hadoop

I'm running a Hadoop single node cluster
while running the

`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal <source> <destination>`

I get only one file from the source directory
And then there is the next source directory.

Furthur, I can't get error and output on running `hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar wordcount`.

I can't see either error or the output?

Please, give me your help?

Answer (score 3):

Just go with this tutorial here: 
[running-a-mapreduce-job by michael noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#running-a-mapreduce-job)

I'm quite sure your namenode or datanode is not up, what are the logs saying?